# Conflicting css hover colors for ul li

Tags: css, hover, html-lists

I've got an issue with two clashing color schemes in a nested ul menu. The words are all white and the top menu item links need to go orange on hover (which they do). But then the sub menu items need to stay white for the letters with an orange background (which they do) but change to an blue background on hover and have the links stay white. Unfortunately I can't seem to have one without messing up the other.

Here is the code. How can I get the sub menu links to stay white on hover?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #3e82ef;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    color: #de9921;
}
#topBar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0px;
    width: 960px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
}
#topBar li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#topBar a, #topBar a:link, #topBar a:visited {
    font-color: #1047A0;
    color: #fff;
}
#topBar a:hover, #topBar a:active {
    color: #de9921;
}
ul.dropdown {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul.dropdown li {
    float: left;
    zoom: 1;
    background: #000;
    margin: 0px;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    color: #fff;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover {
    position: relative;
}
ul.sub_menu li:hover {
    background: #2b94c8;
    color: #fff;
}
/* here is my attempt to keep the links white, but it isn't working */
ul.sub_menu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="topBar">
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li> <a href="/webhome/about/">About</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="/webhome/research/">Staff</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Capabilities</a>
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li><a href="/webhome/capabilities/one">Materials</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webhome/capabilities/one">Automation</a></li>
        <li><a href="/webhome/capabilities/one">Processing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The key to making list-based menus is to style the LINKS, not the LISTS for colors, fonts etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your other CSS is taking precedence. Add the `!important` tag.

```
ul.sub_menu li a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rJLxF/1/)

Comment: It's working in the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rJLxF/1/ the bottom three links stay white onHover.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Must have been a caching issue. I tried it in another browser and it worked. Thanks for the quick and concise response.

Comment: No problem! I originally had a much longer answer, but then I realized that your CSS just had order problems.